# How to iterate an array in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m using filters in Angular JS, however, the list that is displayed in the filter shows the value like this:

**[{"text":"IVA"}{"text":"IVAT0"}]**

This is the `<DIV>` where I´m doing the filter:

```
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label>
                        IMPUESTOS
                      </label>
                    <select ng-model="articulo.impuestos_compra" name="impuestos_compra" class="form-control input-lg" required>
                        <option value="@{{ impuestos_compra }}">@{{ impuestos_compra }}</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
```

And, this is my try to iterate this array:

```
$scope.impuestos_venta = @json($impuestos_venta);


impuestos_compra = ['IVA' , 'IVAT0' ];
        impuestos_compra.forEach(function(impuestos_compra) {
            console.log(impuestos_compra);
        });
```

I want the filter to show both options separately, so the use can select either IVA or IVAT0.

Can you help me please? using the `<option>` tag is not an option, I was asked to bring the values from the database.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your situation right, then you need [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to iterate over your options in the HTML, and then pass the data in the option

```
// This is your array
impuestos_compra = ['IVA' , 'IVAT0' ];
```

**How to use in the View now:**

```
// iterate over the impuestos_compra and then pass it to the option
<select ng-repeat="item in impuestos_compra" class="form-control input-lg" required>
    <option value="item">{{ item }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hahaha! That is why we are here @Rodri6uez . Happy Weekend! Stay safe :)

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for the ng-options attribute

Comment: How do I fix that? I'm newbie to this

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions